# Google App Script: "Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id xxxxx"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**summary**
I want to console.log all the sheets name from all the files stored in some Google Drive folder. And when I try to SpreadSheetApp.openById(xxx) then I got this error

**detail**

- First, I created a list for all the fileId stored in the folder. The script is shown in Appendix 1. I got file ID list w/o any troubles.
- Second, I created another function myAllSheetName. I copied and pasted the file ID list inside this function. and I tried to .getSheets() but I got the error "Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id xxxxxx.
- I show the code in Appendix 2.

**Appendix**
Appendix 1

```
function getFiles(){


  const folderId= 'xxxxxxx';
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const files = folder.getFiles();
  const fileList = [];

  while(files.hasNext()){
    
    let file = files.next();
    let fileId = file.getId(); 
    fileList.push(fileId)
  }  
}
```

Appendix 2

```
function myAllSheetName() {
  let fileList = ['xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx']

  for(let n = 0; n < fileList.length; n++){
    console.log(fileList[n]);
    const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileList[n]).getSheets();
  }
}
```

I tried this script it worked fine.

```
function myAllSheetName() {
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxx').getSheets();
  for(let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    console.log(sheets[i].getName());
  }
  return sheets.map(sheet => sheet.getName());
}
```

So I'm guessing this script has some issue, when trying to access the document ID.

```
const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileList[n]).getSheets();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that in your situation, `fileList` might include the files except for Google Spreadsheet. If my understanding is correct, how about retrieving the file list using `getFilesByType`? When `getFilesByType` is used like `folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS)`, only Google Spreasdheet files are retrieved. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function sample() {
  const folderId = '###'; // Please set your folder ID.

  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  const fileList = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    let fileId = file.getId();
    fileList.push(fileId)
  }
  const res = [];
  for (let n = 0; n < fileList.length; n++) {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileList[n]);
    res.push({ spreadsheetTitle: ss.getName(), spreadsheetId: fileList[n], sheetNames: ss.getSheets().map(s => s.getSheetName()) });
  }
  console.log(res);
}
```

- When this script is run, the Spreadsheet files are retrieved and all sheet names in each Spreadsheet are retrieved.

#### Note:

- As additional information, in this case, `const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS)` is the same with `` const files = folder.searchFiles(`mimeType='${MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}' and trashed=false`) ``.

#### Reference:

- [getFilesByType(mimeType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfilesbytypemimetype)

Comment: > fileList might include the files except for Google Spreadsheet. 
this was the issue. after i changed all the file from excel to spreadsheet, it worked perfectly fine